# django admin choices with submenus

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, field

I have a model with this field:

```
exercise = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=EXERCISES_CHOICES)
```

but the list of exercises is VERY long, when I use it in the admin interface it occupies all the length of the page, is there a way to display in subitems?

Comment: When you say "list of exercises is VERY long", are you talking about the select widget?

Comment: yes the list box is very long ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, but mine is not a list of choices - instead it is a foreign key field and the default in the Admin is also to display the entire list of available values in an option menu; as the database fills, this will probably be unusable.  My plan is to create a custom Admin widget which uses a text input instead of an option menu, and use autocomplete to help fill in the value.  I have not yet implemented it - I've started looking for autocomplete packages.  Maybe once I decide on one, I'll come back and post an update.

P.S.  It seems to me this would be a common problem and should already have been solved.  Why can't I find anything out there?

---- EDIT ----

Apparently this **has** been solved!  According to its documentation, the "django-extensions" package includes a "ForeignKeyAutocompleteAdmin" class.  Hurray!  See here:

http://pythonhosted.org/django-extensions/admin_extensions.html

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-extensions

Disclaimer: I haven't tried it yet (but I intend to!)